# Solidity, how to cast SmartContract type to address

Tags: solidity, interfaces, type-casting

I am currently a bit stuck with my contract, the issue is following:
I define a smartcontract type which is used for another address (aka address is smartcontract that provides the specified interface)
The question is whether there is a possibility to make address type checks or cast said contract interface object to address, since that what it's essentially. While I know that in terms of storage those are bytes that represent address, I just can't seem to figure out how to get from interface type back to bare address type and make proper checks against it.
I searched around for quite a bit, but couldn't find any samples how to accomplish this on the web or in the solidity docs.

See example bellow:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract SampleInterface {
    function foo(uint256 someValue) external returns (uint256);
}

library SampleLibrary {
    enum SampleType {
        FIRST,
        SECOND
    }
}

contract SampleInterfaceManager {
    mapping(uint => SampleInterface[]) public interfacesByType;

    function processFoo(uint256 someValue, SampleLibrary.SampleType sampleType) external returns (uint256) {
        SampleInterface[] storage sampleInterfaces = interfacesByType[uint(sampleType)];
        uint temp = someValue;
        for (uint i = 0; i < sampleInterfaces.length; i++) {
            SampleInterface sampleInterface = sampleInterfaces[i];

            //How to make this check work?

            if (sampleInterface != address(0)) {
                temp = sampleInterface.foo(temp);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

This code currently creates compilation error:

```
smartcontracts/Sample.sol:23:17: Error: Operator != not compatible with types contract SampleInterface and address payable
            if (sampleInterface != address(0)) {
                ^---------------------------^
```

Any advice on how to solve this is most welcome. I can try and do without this check but would rather hope to avoid this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just cast to `address`:

```
if (address(sampleInterface) != address(0)) {
```